# Importing data from .txt file into excel macro sheet without changing the format and formulae in the exported sheet

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am trying to import data from a .txt file to a sheet in my excel file that has specific format and formulas in some of the cells. I would like to import the data without changing the format or formulas in the original sheet.

This is the vba command that I use for that.

```
Sub Import()

Dim fileToOpen As Variant
Dim fileFilterPattern As String
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wbTextImport As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

fileFilterPattern = "Text Files (*.txt; *.csv), *.txt; *.csv"

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename

If fileToOpen = False Then
    ' Input Cancelled
    MsgBox "No file selected"
Else
    ' We have a file to open
    

    Workbooks.OpenText _
            Filename:=fileToOpen, _
            StartRow:=6, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            Tab:=True
            

    Set wbTextImport = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Range("A6")

    wbTextImport.Close False

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

When I import the formatting and the formulas in the excel sheet vanishes. So I would like the excel sheet to retain all the formatting and formulas and just import data in the cells.

Comment: Do you mean _just import data into the cells **without  formulas**_ ?

Comment: In whitch area exist the formulas you need unchanged?  what is the address of wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion ?

Comment: @CDP1802 No, I have the formulas in the table in the excel sheet to which I upload the data. For eg. The data I want to upload is in the data.txt file, and the data.xlm excel file have a table with formulas. I want to just upload the numbers in the respective cells in the table without disturbing the formula of format of the table in my data.xlm file.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ Please refer my above comment. wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion - That is the address of the worksheet with a table in which I want my data to be uploaded

Comment: What dimentions have the data? how many rows, how many columns? After uploaded you copy the data in original sheet. So the data overlaps the cells you want to not. So i ask:  1) Whitch cells you don't want to change?  2) What is the address of the data to be copied ? (e.g A6: Z1500)

Comment: --- Do you want to copy the cells one by one but leave the cells that contain formulas in the original sheet intact?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the location of the formulas in the excel sheet that vanishes